# A tough loop in a contest

Tags: c, loops

Today I got a irritating question in a coding contest. I creamed through the first round but in the second round the following question got me in a trap.

```
Question: Input N = 4
          Output:
                 1
                 0 1
                 1 0 1
                 0 1 0 1
```

I tried many things but every time I failed.

Apart from this stupid wrong solution I tried many fancy stuff and failed in the end.
What part of my C knowledge is weak?

If you were given this question how would you solve it?

Comment: Your while loop condition has N in it but you're using i within the loop. This makes about zero sense to me.

Comment: You might want to repost your code since now it seems like you tried nothing and are asking people to solve the problem for you.

Comment: Simple answer, loops. Downvotes are there to help you learn as well. The exercise seems explicitly designed to test how well you know loops in C. I honestly don't think that would be that hard to figure out.

Comment: I tried about a 100 things and none of them worked should I repost all of that? And if you feel like I tried nothing then I dont know what to say or how to prove it to you

Comment: Your question says: `Apart from this stupid wrong solution`...what stupid solution? I see no solution posted or no try at it either.

Comment: Loops seriously but loops seem so simple to me. Even the  user H2CO3 also found this trivial, at least someone agrees with me

Comment: He found it simple because he knows how loops work. Its no big deal. Practice. But if you think there's some magic going on, ask H2CO3

Comment: Now it seems so simple after reading what H2CO3, viggy and Eric Jalbow have said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the job for me.

```
int i,j,flag;
int num=4;

flag=1;
for(i=0;i<num;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<i+1;j++)
    {
            printf("%d",(j+flag)%2);
    }
    if(flag)
    {
            flag=0;
    }
    else
    {
            flag=1;
    }
    printf("\n");

 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Seems pretty trivial to me:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                    printf("%d ", i % 2 ? j % 2 : 1 - j % 2);
            }
            printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You came up with this solution just now, I mean right after you saw the code?

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I guess its PRACTICE. Now I am back to KN King.

Answer (score 2):

You panicked.  Since the values you print depend on the row and column, use both.  And name your variables better.

```
void printBinaryTriangle(const unsigned int rows) {
    for(int row = 1; row <= rows; ++row) {
        for (int column = 0; column < row; ++column) {
            printf("%d ", (row + column) % 2);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not just write a `main` method because you may need to get the number of rows from different sources in the future, instead of fixing `4`.  This is a contest problem, but you can still think about future uses.  When you are programming as part of your job, you need to remember that requirements change.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
for(int k = 0; k < N; k++){
    for(int i = 0; i < k+1; i++){
        if(i % 2 == k % 2)
           printf("1 ");
        else
           printf("0 ");
    };
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: What about newline and spaces?

Answer (score -2):

```
num = 12
new_string = ''
new_list = ''
while num:
    for i in range(1,num+1):
        strings_of_ones = new_string+ '1' * i
        new_list = list(strings_of_ones)
        for j in range(1,len(new_list),2):
            new_list[j]='0'
        print(' '.join(new_list[::-1]))
        num -= 1
```

Comment: You answered using python(?) code while the question was about c. Also please provide some details and not only code.

Answer (score -2):

Answer in Java:-

```
public class practice {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n=4;
        for (int i=1 ;i<=n ; i++) {
            for (int j=1 ;j<=i ;j++) {
                int a=i+j;
                if (a % 2==0) {
                    System.out.print("1"+" ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("0"+" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        

}
```

}